# Conditional addition or row to dataframe based on time

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I need to create a summarised dataframe from an existing dataframe, here is an example of the current dataframe:

```
df1 = data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-04-11 21:46:55",
                                         "2019-04-13 00:19:23",
                                         "2019-04-15 01:20:41",
                                         "2019-04-15 04:18:12",
                                         "2019-04-24 05:54:17",
                                         "2019-04-22 08:44:41",
                                         "2019-04-23 03:49:31",
                                         "2019-04-23 03:45:21",
                                         "2019-04-23 00:50:45",
                                         "2019-04-22 09:16:08",
                                         "2019-04-23 07:21:36",
                                         "2019-04-23 07:24:53")), order = c(1,3,4,5,9,7,6,6,6,7,7,7))
```

The function/loop needs to return rows equal to `length(unique(order)`, in this case that would be 7 rows. Ultimately I will calculate a time difference between the rows, so I always need each row to be sequential in time (yielding positive values). Where `datetime` of current row precedes a previous row there needs to be a conditional check that rejects the addition of that row and chooses the first row that exists after the time of the previous `datetime`.

In the example above `order` 7 has three rows. For this `order`, The row that should be returned is `2019-04-23 07:21:36  7` based on the fact that order 6 has datetime `2019-04-23 00:50:45` thus `2019-04-22 08:44:41` would precede the `datetime` of the previous row which cannot happen and would therefore be rejected.

Importantly the function/loop shouldn't just find any row that has a datetime which comes after the previous row, but it should be the first possible row that meets this criteria (thus in the above case `"2019-04-23 07:20:00"` should be discarded as well). So I can't use something like `df1 %>% arrange(datetime) %>% group_by(order) %>% slice_max(1)`

The output should be this:

```
new.df = data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-04-11 21:46:55",
                                            "2019-04-13 00:19:23",
                                            "2019-04-15 01:20:41",
                                            "2019-04-15 04:18:12",
                                            "2019-04-23 00:50:45",
                                            "2019-04-23 07:21:36",
                                            "2019-04-24 05:54:17")), order = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,9))
```

Cheers

Comment: Would `filter(df1, order >= cummax(order))` work?

Comment: I don't think so. It works on the small above example but not on my large df. I'm not sure why though. Unfortunately I can't repex the df as it's too large...but basically each datetime/order combination has thousands of rows....and I only need to return `length(unique(order))`. Typically 13 rows or less.

Comment: Upon re-reading I think `dplyr::filter(df1, order > cummax(dplyr::lag(order, default = -1)))` would be better.

Comment: Seems close. But it's not putting all distinct `order` rows. i.e. let's say that there are supposed to be 7 rows, it only returns 6. As when I check through `df %>% distinct(order)` there are 7 uniques

Comment: It could happen that there is an order that is completely before another order with a higher number. In that case you want it to be rejected. That way, there can be fewer distinct orders after applying this filtering than before. For example, changing the first 7 and 9 in your example causes the order 7 to be rejected.

Comment: `df1%>%  group_by(order) %>% filter( datetime==max(datetime))  %>% arrange(datetime) %>%   as.data.frame()`

Comment: R.S. Simply taking `max(datetime)` won't do I'm afraid. It need to be the first possible datetime in sequence.

Comment: @Bas. I think you're correct. However, if this case arises what should happen is that the later order with an earlier time should be discarded instead. Thus the code should work through the rows progressively and find one that is later in sequence to return. It shouldn't be that one row is rejected immediately.

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem. Could you create a minimal example that catches all the edge cases, together with the expected output? Are you looking for a [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)? What if all order 7 were before the order 6?

Comment: @Bas I think now the issue is reproducible... I've changed the initial df and new df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the easiest solution, but it does work for your example.

First, we order by date and filter streaks of the same `order`, keeping only the first one. This throws away the second and third `6` and the third and fourth `7`.
Then, we reverse sort by date and apply the filter I proposed as a comment before, but with `cummin`, thus making sure that we only keep rows that are less than any previous row. This tosses away the first `7`.
Then, we sort by date again to get the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  filter(order != lag(order, default = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(datetime)) %>% 
  filter(order <= cummin(order)) %>% 
  arrange(datetime)
```

Which gives

```
             datetime order
1 2019-04-11 21:46:55     1
2 2019-04-13 00:19:23     3
3 2019-04-15 01:20:41     4
4 2019-04-15 04:18:12     5
5 2019-04-23 00:50:45     6
6 2019-04-23 07:21:36     7
7 2019-04-24 05:54:17     9
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. We shall see if I can apply this to the bunch of data frames I have without anything else coming up!